# Time loading webpage

Tags: time, load, minify

I'm trying many problems with the time loading of my web page:

www.alvaromillan.es.

I've tried to minify the js and the images but the problem is, as you can see, that my web site is only this page so every image and js is on this document...
The loading time is really high and even the smooth scrolling movement lasts a lot and the first time you use it it doesn´t go fine...

Please may any of you help me??

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the page just using the chrome developer tools and while there are probably several things you can do which YSlow would suggest, I think the biggest gain would come from optimizing and spriting your images. 131 of the 156 requests on your page are for images. Thats alot of images and many are fairly small. Also alot of the images seem quite large in bytes for their size. Here is what I would do:

1. Combine the images using several sprite sheets about 50k-100k per sheet.
2. Use the PNG format.
3. Quantize the sprite sheets to 8bit PNGs. My guess is that you will not experience perceptible quality loss by doing this. You could use spmething like [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) to do this.
4. Use something like [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) to apply lossless compression on the quantized image.

I think this will yield dramatic improvements.

As skaffman suggests, do run yslow and/or google [page speed test](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/) for more thorough suggestions. I also like using webpagetest.org which provides great metrics for optimizing pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it! And how many images would you recomend me to put in each sprite sheet?

Comment: I'd try to make each sheet not much more than 50k. That's just a number that I use and seems reasonable. It is a bad idea to have a single sprite that is too huge since most browsers would be unable to take advantage of parralelzation.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt, I'll try it and I'll tell you!

Comment: Hello, I did what you told me and the result is good but it´s not enough... the web is still really slow and I think the problem could be there are many images which cant be in a sprite sheet (they are the images from each proyect which are loaded in a fancybox...). Do you think there could be another good tip to reduce the time loading of my web? By the way, here is the web: www.alvaromillan.es

Comment: Yeah it does look better but still taking about 6 seconds to reach doc complete in the US (where I am but perhaps not where your viewers are). I think you have done what you can with spriting and image optimization. Fortunately most of your image loading is deferred until after doc complete(nice). The longest request is now to http://www.alvaromillan.es/formulario/formulario.php and its in the time that the server takes to send it (about 4 seconds). So I would look to see what you can so on the server to make that faster.Since it is server time, it will be this slow regardless of user location

Comment: Some other optimizations: Make sure your web server is configured to gzip the data sent out. It is currently uncompressed. Turn on keep-alives on your web server. Load jquery once. Looks like you are loading two different versions. Add far future expires headers to your static content and propperly configured ETags. That will atleast cause the page to rnder much faster on requests after the browser's first request.

Answer (score 0):

Give the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) Firefox plugin a try. It will analyze the load times of your site and advise you the best course of action to take to fix it.

Comment: Hello, I did what you told me and the result is good but it´s not enough... the web is still really slow and I think the problem could be there are many images which cant be in a sprite sheet (they are the images from each proyect which are loaded in a fancybox...). Do you think there could be another good tip to reduce the time loading of my web? By the way, here is the web: www.alvaromillan.es

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's some quick initial thoughts...

Flush the page after the head so that the browser can start downloading those resources sooner.

Remove the iframe

jquery appears to be loaded twice - once directly and once via google.load

Can you defer the loading of the javascript until later e.g. put it at the bottom of the page or load it asynchronously?

Rather than preloading the slideshow images - why not load them on demand when clicked on, or lazy load them after the page has finished load?

Also do you really want IE to emulate IE6???

Comment: Well I've proved almost everything but the loading is still taking too long... I think the problem could be the javascript which load all the images... I'd like this javascript to be loaded just when the user clicks on a thumbnail (this javascript is a lightbox) but I don´t know how to do it. I've read about lazy load and on demand but I couldn't get it... 

But I'd like to do the lazy or on demand stuff... Could you please help me?

Comment: Now I have this js as: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeslideshow.js">function downloadJSAtOnload(){var element=document.createElement("script");element.src="js/fadeslideshow.js";document.body.appendChild(element);}
if(window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load",downloadJSAtOnload,false);else if(window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload",downloadJSAtOnload);else window.onload=downloadJSAtOnload;</script>

Comment: Looking at the waterfall, I'm pretty sure the iframe is the problem - in Chrome it's blocking the page for about 3.5s. Do you really need the contact form to be in the iframe - can't you just include it on the page?